# twitter bootstrap 3 tab view fade does not work properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use twitter bootstrap 3 applying `.fade` to show tabs with fade. That's fine except for the first tab's content is not shown for the first time:

http://jsfiddle.net/tVSv9/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

    <div id='content' class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="home">
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
        <ul>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">
          this is my message
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings"></div>
    </div>
```

Where is the problem inside the code?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to add `in` class to your active tab content

The reason behind is there is predefined style in bootstrap css `.fade.in {opacity: 1;}` so if you are using `.fade` in tab then you need to add `.in` too

See this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tVSv9/3/)**

HTML

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
```

Comment: A much cleaner way to do so. Though I will keep my answer here as alternative. And it does give the 'fade in' effect the moment page is loaded.

Comment: I apologize for resurrecting an old post but is there any way to use fade without an active default tab?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit peculiar, but I could think of a quick hack to get this running.

```
$('.nav li.active').removeClass('active').find('a').trigger('click');
```

Put the above script inside `$(document).ready( function() { ... })`

What it does is basically remove your pre-defined active class, and re-enable it by mocking the 'click' event.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jofrysutanto/tVSv9/2/

Answer (score 0):

Also worth mentioning,

This will work:

```
$('#yourtabs a:first').tab('show');
$('.tab-pane:first').addClass('fade in');
```

This won't:

```
$('.tab-pane:first').addClass('fade in');
$('#yourtabs a:first').tab('show');
```

Otherwise your .fade will be hidden on init.